# ignore particular warning in RStudio IDE

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm working on functions which catches input variables and preprocess them before evaluation.
I would like to ignore RStudio warning (yellow triangle) with tooltip message `missing argument to function call`.
Below code is detected by RStudio as warning which in my use case is not a warning.

```
f = function(a, b) match.call()
f(a = list("a","b",,"d",,,"g",), b = list(,,"c"))
```

Missing argument is valid use case.
Can I somehow set to ignore this type of warning?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `options` to turn all warnings off. The argument is `showWarnCalls` and is a boolean. Use as such:

`options(showWarnCalls = FALSE)`

Please note this is dangerous as this turns off *all* of your warnings. Perhaps you could turn warnings off before running the function that commits them and then turn them back on afterward. Example:

```
options(showWarnCalls = FALSE)

### Your Code ###

options(showWarnCalls = TRUE)
```